# Настройки для catalog.item в битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Где узнать для компонента catalog.item параметры и настройки? Весь гугл прошуршал нет вообще ничего про него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как бы у компонентов есть файл .parameters.php

У данного его нет. Но в классе явно написано что параметры принимаются все.

По сути это пустышка в которую в параметры передаются стандартные параметры и все что в голову взбредет но в классе компонента есть инструкция которая пихает в arResult свойство 'RESULT' из параметров